Hosting option does not appear in ng add @angular/fire
I’m at the beginning of developing an Angular system. I’ve already configured Firebase in the console with what I need, verified the logged-in account with firebase-tools, and when I try to add @angular/fire using the command ng add @angular/fire, the hosting option does not appear.
The only options that appear are:

Authentication

Google Analytics

App Check

Firestore

Realtime Database

Cloud Function (callable)

Cloud Messaging

Performance Monitoring

Cloud Storage

Remote Config

VertexAi (preview)


I can’t find the option I need, which is Hosting.
I did manage to add some of these options like Authentication, Firestore, and Cloud Storage without any issues.
I’m not sure if this feature was removed or if it’s activated differently now. I’d prefer not to use firebase-tools directly; the angular/fire library used to handle this quite well.
Versions:

angular: 17.3.7

angular/fire: 17.1.0

firebase: 13.10.0

nodejs: 20.12.2

npm: 10.5.0


What I’ve tried/what happened:

Created an Angular project.

Set up and configured a Firebase project.

Added angular/fire to the project using ng add @angular/fire.

Selected the project, account, and desired features.

Couldn’t find the hosting option.


What I expected:

Create an Angular project.

Set up and configure a Firebase project.

Add angular/fire to the Angular project using ng add @angular/fire.

Select and add all desired features (hosting, Firestore, storage, and authentication).

Continue developing the system.



I've been using the Angular CLI + AngularFire for a while and I ran into this issue the other day as well. It appears that the 17.1.0 release no longer supports this by default.
Quick Workaround:
Add the previous version of AngularFire to your project with:
ng add @angular/fire@17.0.1
This version does have the automatic hosting provisioning as part of the install so hopefully that works for you. Then once you've finished the init, you can update the package with:
ng update @angular/fire
Then ng deploy should still work even after updating.

Note this line in the AngularFire source code mentions:

Legacy ng-deploy Firebase is deprecated.

So, I'm not sure how long this will continue to work ️. Hopefully someone else can detail the appropriate way to enable this feature moving forward because the AngularFire docs do not appear to reflect this change yet.

Thank you very much for the response, Ashtin. I ended up using the command firebase init hosting, and it worked incredibly well. As far as I remember, it used to be necessary to activate something related to web frameworks, and I don't remember if it was necessary to change the baseHref. But now, if I create a project with Firebase, I will definitely do what you suggested.
It's a pity they deprecated it; it was such an easy way to use Firebase with Angular. With just one library, we could do most things.
Anyway, thank you very much!

Note - This trick only works if you start with a v17 Angular app. Just for fun I tried using the angular fire version mentioned above with the v18 CLI and as expected it wouldn't let me add the dependency due to a version mismatch. You can still start with the v17 and then go through the entire upgrade process after you've configured your hosting. Or, add the hosting in a clean repo and check the changes and duplicate that in a new v18 project though. Hope that helps!
